# Payment intent not found when refunding

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments

How do I refund money from a connected account?
I tried putting `stripeAccount` to `refunds.create` method:

```
const refund = await stripe.refunds.create({
  payment_intent: validPaymentIntentId, // "pi_randomid"
  amount: validAmount,
}, { stripeAccount: validStripeAccountId });
```

And it says that the payment intent is not found:

> No such payment_intent: 'pi_randomid'

This is how I create a payment intent:

```
const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
  amount, currency, customer,

  on_behalf_of: stripeAccountId,
  transfer_data: {
    destination: stripeAccountId,
  },
});
```

So payment intents created on behalf of a connected account. And when it has to be refunded I want the money to refund be taken from the connected account. But it says that the payment intent is not found even though it is listed on the dashboard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the payment intent creation request with `transfer_data.destination`, you're using [Destination Charges](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/destination-charges). The payment intent is created on the platform, **not** connected account.

When you perform refund on the platform, `stripeAccount` shouldn't be used as it's meant for payment intent created on the connected account. That's why you faced the error since the payment intent is created on platform.

To refund a Destination Charges, you simply [refund](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/destination-charges#issuing-refunds) with platform secret key. For example,

```
const refund = await stripe.refunds.create({
  payment_intent: 'pi_xxx',
  reverse_transfer: true,
});
```

Comment: Good answer. It saved a day to me. Thank you.